# How to update content holders' content via pages in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, updates

I am comparatively new to wordpress.

I have a requirement here that needs the following

- I need to have content holders like [Image, Text] (2 columns in a section)
  [Image, Text, Text] ( 3 columns in a section).
- I need to define the contents of these in **pages** whilst I can create content holders 
  for these linking them to custom templates [using **"multiple content holder"** plug-in].

My questions are the following

- Can you help me with some examples of using the above mentioned plug-in? Or, direct me to a different plug-in.
- How do I add content via pages for the above scenario? I should be able to create different pages with diff content like saying text = ""; image1=""; image2="" (or in similar terms). And wordpress should use the template/plugin to render the page.